# Powershell export to CSV

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv, get-childitem

I am trying to create a report of files that are one day old, I currently have a script to include filename and date:

```
get-childitem -Path \\UNC_PATH_TO_FILE
         | where-object {$_.lastwritetime -gt (get-date).addDays(-1)}
         | Foreach-Object { $_.Name, $_.CreationTime }
```

Previously I was exporting this to a file for each UNC path, however this has now grown and will result in 22 separate files to be read.

I want to consolidate this into a CSV file which can contain a coll for **Server**, **Filename** (`$_.Name`) and **Date** (`$_.CreationTime`).

This is outside of my Powershell realm and cannot find anything to really help me. Would someone be able to offer some assistance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
$paths = "\\server1\unc\path", "\\server1\unc\path" 
Get-ChildItem -Path $paths
         | Where-Object {$_.lastwritetime -gt (Get-Date).addDays(-1)}
         | Select-Object @{n="Server";e={([uri]$_.FullName).Host}},
                         @{n="Filename";e={$_.Name}},
                         @{n="Date";e={$_.CreationTime}},
                         @{n="FileSize(MB)";e={[Math]::Round($_.Length/1MB,3)}}
         | Export-Csv test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

It extracts the servername from the UNC path and renames the other properties with the names you specified.

Comment: Thanks for that, it gives me part of what I am looking for. I just want to be able to query multiple servers at once. But this will give me one CSV for each server instead of one CSV, would you know how I could achieve this please? Thanks again.

Comment: Try the updated answer. Using a `$path` string-array to supply the paths.

Comment: Brilliant thanks, that has done the trick. Do you know the command for file size as well? I can only find very complicated processes for this, nothing as simple as "$_.Name, $_.CreationTime, etc.

Comment: I've updated with filesize in MB now, with sizes rounded up to 3 decimal-places. If you need to modify it(ex. KB or 2 decimal-places), I think you'll find it out yourself :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that creates a new object for each file:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path \\UNC_PATH_TO_FILE |
Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)} | 
ForEach-Object { 
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        Server = $_.FullName -replace '^\\\\([\w]+)\\.+$','$1'
        Name = $_.Name
        CreationTime = $_.CreationTime    
    }
} | Export-Csv -Path files.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
get-childitem -Path \\UNC_PATH_TO_FILE
         | where { $_.lastwritetime -gt (get-date).AddDays(-1)} 
         | foreach-object { $env.COMPUTERNAME,$_.Name, $_.CreationTime}
         | Export-Csv -Path foo.txt -NoTypeInformation
```